# JSF/Primefaces span onClick automatically calls Backing Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am doing a project in JSF and I ran into the following issue.

When I create the following span:

```
<ui:composition>
    <div id="header" class="header">
        <p style="float: right; padding-right: 20px">
            Welcome, #{infoGet.username} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" style="color: darkred; cursor: pointer;" onclick="#{Login.logout()}" />
        </p>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

It calls this method logout()

```
public void logout() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("Landing.xhtml");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However on page load the onClick inside the span gets automatically called, if I do:

```
public void logout() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
}
```

And refresh the page the session will be invalidated.

Is there a way to call a method "onClick" from a span? I do need it to be a Label so I can properly use the Bootstrap icon elements. I know onClick is usually used for Javascript, but it would seem logical for it to work with JSF.

EDIT with solution by @luiggi-mendoza

Changed the composition to:

```
<ui:composition>
    <div id="header" class="header">
        <h:form style="float: right; padding-right: 20px">
            <h:commandLink action="#{Login.logout()}" styleClass="clearCommand">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" style="color: darkred; cursor: pointer;" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
        <p style="float: right; padding-right: 20px">
            Welcome, #{infoGet.username}
        </p>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Made clearCommand:

```
#clearCommand {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Left the login as it was, and everything works out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call any Expression Language directly into a non-JSF component. What you're looking for is for an `<h:commandLink>` instead:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{Login.logout()}" styleClass="foo">
        <span style="...">logout</span>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Where `foo` is a CSS class where you clear the default formatting for an `<a>`. Then, you can use the common HTML `<span>` component to apply the desired CSS to your logout text.